How do methods and/or configurations scroll programmatically to ListView.builder indexes in flutter?
 ListView.builder(
                    itemExtent: 60,
                    itemCount: controller.lotQueryList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (c, i) {}
)

f I have a listview.builder list of about 5000 items, how can I jump to the 2000th item using a function or configuration?

first you have to find out the height of the item. and then you can scoll to that position. using scroll controller.

How can I initialize the position where I need to scroll, but not where I need to scroll

you can either give itemExtent value to the builder. aor use a package named scrollable_positioned_list

Suppose item height is 60 px as supposed in item extent, you could navigate to the middle of the list:
scrollController.animateTo(
    (listLenght ~/ 2) * 60 ,
    curve: Curves.easeOut,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
 );

and to animate going to the end of the list:
scrollController.animateTo(
    scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
    curve: Curves.easeOut,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
 );


How can I initialize the position where I need to scroll, but not where I need to scroll

@laterday, what do you mean, could you restate your question?
